# Kotlin - Instance cannot retrieve it's class annotations via myInstance::class.annotations but can with javaClass.annotations

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection, annotations

I've encountered strange behaviour when trying to read Class's annotations from an object.

For example:

```kotlin
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
annotation class MyAnnotation(val value: String) {}


@MyAnnotation("HelloWorld")
class MyClass 

// in test
val obj = MyClass()
println(obj::class.annotations) // DOESN'T finds annotation
println(obj::class.java.annotations) // finds annotation
println(obj.javaClass.annotations) // finds annotation
```

However, it does find it when I make direct reference to a class like so:

```kotlin
println(MyClass::class.annotations) // finds annotation
```

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: What Kotlin version are you using? I'm using 1.3.72 and first case prints out `[@test.MyAnnotation(value="HelloWorld")]`

Comment: Strangely enough, after restarting Android Studio 3 times I finally get the non empty array O.o without any code change.. Feels scary

Answer (score 0):

I will keep the question open for some more time, since after restarting android studio it started showing annotation in the list, w/o any code change.